# using lodash merge causes not to update array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

I am doing an update of a request of data. So in my code I find the current record and do a `_.merge(client, request)`. client is the db record and request has the client object.

In my schema i have an array of objects which come through the request as follows:

Class: 'science'
Students: [{Name: 'xxxxx',
    dobDay: 5,
    dobMonth: 7,
    dobYear: 2008,
    notes: 'jjj',
    _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e',
  },
  { Name: 'test2',
    dobDay: 3,
    dobMonth: 2,
    dobYear: 2005,,
    notes: 'te' } ]

This includes the additional record push onto the array where the Name is test2.

The db record retrieved is:

```
 Class: 'science'
```

Students:[{Name: 'xxxxx',
    dobDay: 5,
    dobMonth: 7,
    dobYear: 2008,
    notes: 'jjj',
    _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e',
  }]

when the merge is carried out the result is that the first record entry in array will be duplicated in the 2nd element like below:

```
  Class: 'science'
```

Students:[{ Name: 'xxxxx',
        dobDay: 5,
        dobMonth: 7,
        dobYear: 2008,
        notes: 'jjj',
        _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e',
      } ,
     { Name: 'xxxxx',
        dobDay: 5,
        dobMonth: 7,
        dobYear: 2008,
        notes: 'jjj',
        _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e',
      }]

my line of code is  var updated = _.merge(client, requestClient);

Any help would be great

thanks

EDITED:

Format of object which is merging is

```
    var a = {
 testname: 'test1',
 students: [ 
  { Name: 'xxxxx',
    dobDay: 5,
    dobMonth: 7,
    dobYear: 2008,
    notes: 'jjj',
    _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e',
  }, 
  { 
    Name: 'test2',
    dobDay: 3,
    dobMonth: 2,
    dobYear: 2005,
    notes: 'te' 
  } 
]};

var b = {
 testname: 'test1',
  students: [ 
  { 
    Name: 'xxxxx',
    dobDay: 5,
    dobMonth: 7,
    dobYear: 2008,
    notes: 'jjj',
    _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e'
  }
]};

console.log(_.unionWith(a,b,_.isEqual));
```

Answer (score 0):

`_.merge` is for object, since you're working with array you should try `_.union` it'll merge your two array and remove duplicates

```
_.unionBy(client, requestClient, '_id')
```

Comment: Thanks but the object has other properties including the array so will that work?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well, is client or requestClient half  object half array ? if yes could you post an exemple of what it look like ?

Comment: I've tested `merge` with arrays and got expected result (see in console) https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/curn0jto/

Comment: I have edited the example so a basic rep is class name who's name can also be changed

Comment: It's when their is an object with an array object which causes issues

Comment: You should look at Keith's answer, it's like mine but more detailed, also it can work for some case with merge because in js an array is derived from an object, but you'll often end wit unexpected result, so you should stick with methods for arrays ;)

Comment: I also edited my answer to use `unionBy` instead of `union` to prevent a duplicate to come

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your after.. ?

```js
var a = [ 
  { Name: 'xxxxx',
    dobDay: 5,
    dobMonth: 7,
    dobYear: 2008,
    notes: 'jjj',
    _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e',
  }, 
  { 
    Name: 'test2',
    dobDay: 3,
    dobMonth: 2,
    dobYear: 2005,
    notes: 'te' 
  } 
];

var b = [ 
  { 
    Name: 'xxxxx',
    dobDay: 5,
    dobMonth: 7,
    dobYear: 2008,
    notes: 'jjj',
    _id: '58263fa92eb2295b2b0dcf7e'
  }
];

console.log(_.unionWith(a,b,_.isEqual));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have edited my question to show the object. All the object is merge which includes the array

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanks for the help but ended up using the following:

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
      if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
        return _.merge(objValue, srcValue);
      }
    };

    var requestClient = req.body.client;
    var updated = _.mergeWith(client, requestClient, customizer);
```

lodash has the _.mergeWith where i used the customizer function to merge the array objects seperately.

Might be a better solution so always up for comments :)